# How do I create a custom "game over" alert similar to Flappy Bird?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

Very new to swift and coding in general so please go easy ):

How would I go about creating a custom UIAlert similar to how Flappy Bird ends the game.  I'm assuming it's just some sort of container node that appears after the game ends? Seems simple enough but I'm not sure where to start.  Any advice would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/ios

Comment: separate container node is really all you need, you are correct on that.

Comment: They are all images, just add the to the scene the normal way, make them hidden or not depending on the state.

Answer (score 1):

Flappy Bird isn't using UIAlert, everything is running in OpenGL render code inside a GLESView, since you're rendering sprites inside some GLESView, it will be easier if you just use it to render your custom alert or whatever other game state your game require, rather than transitioning using native components. It will be more cross-platform compatible too :)

Comment: he is using sprite kit so it is not a GLESView